# How to load a type in parent-child website

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, asp.net

I am developing a C# VS 2008 / SQL Server 2008 website.  Although this same code compiles in the Project version, the website version does not compile.  Many of their files are the same so I do not understand even where to look.  The only compile error I get is:

Could not load type 'DataMatch'

in my DataMatch.aspx file.  Is the problem in my web.config file?  How do websites differ from projects in VS?  All four of these files reside in same directory.

Default.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="AddFileToSQL" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

Default.aspx.cs file:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace AddFileToSQL
{
    public partial class AddFileToSQL : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

...
```

DataMatch.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataMatch.aspx.cs"
Inherits="DataMatch" %>
```

DataMatch.aspx.cs file:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AddFileToSQL;

public partial class DataMatch : AddFileToSQL
{

...
```

Comment: can you post the compilation errors?

Comment: I did.  See above.  All it says is "Could not load type 'DataMatch'"

Comment: No, not deploying, just building and debugging.  Please see below comment.

Answer (score 1):

are you deploying it to a subdirectory on your website?  if so the line:

```
MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
```

might be unable to find the master file.

Comment: I have a hunch I know what the problem is now.  I think the problem is that in this website, I have two subfolders which I store ASPX files in for security reasons.  But my project does not have any subfolders.